# How can I get a count() in a join?

Tags: sql

I have two tables. Call them jars and cookies. A cookie has one jar, a jar has zero or more cookies. The cookies table has a cookies.jar_id field for the reference.

What I want is a list of all jars that have cookies (excluding jars that have zero cookies), with a count of the number of cookies in each jar.

There may be millions of jars, and millions of cookies, so this is performance-sensitive. And 99% of jars have zero cookies, while those that have cookies may have hundreds of them, so I really need to exclude empty jars and not return a row for every cookie.

I'm sure this can be done somehow with a join, but I'm stumped.

Comment: The answer is the use of `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 5):

You actually need to query the 'cookies' table only:

```
Select jar_id, count(*) as NumberOfCookies
From cookies
Where jar_id is not null
Group by jar_id
```

Comment: `A cookie has one jar` that should imply jar_id in cookies table is always not null

Comment: The query will group the cookies by jar omitting cookies without jars if any.

Answer (score 4):

```
select jars.jar_id, count(*)
from jars
inner join cookies 
on cookies.jar_id = jars.jar_id
group by jars.jar_id
```

There should be an index on cookies.jar_id. Better even have a foreign key from cookies.jar_id to jars.jar_id

If you want to add other columns from the jars table to the result, use the Max() aggregate function:

```
select jars.jar_id, Max(jars.jar_name), count(*)
from jars
inner join cookies 
on cookies.jar_id = jars.jar_id
group by jars.jar_id
```

Comment: No need to query the 'jars' table

Comment: Not for this resultset, yes. But the next question will be how to also have the jar name ;-)

Comment: Well, not sure about that need, anyway the execution plan will be more complex and will take more time to run. He wanted something efficient.

Comment: Well, not so much the jar name, but a bunch of other interesting jar factoids (like the shelf id, since each jar belongs to a shelf). But given the guidance so far, I can build a list of fancy jar information by using these examples as the basis of a subquery. This has been very helpful.